# How to find memory used by NSString?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I got stuck when trying to look at the memory used by NSString:

My NSString theKey shows fine in lldb:

```
(lldb) p *theKey
(NSString) $5 = {
  NSObject = {
    isa = __NSCFConstantString
  }
}
```

The content is visible:

```
(lldb) po theKey
BBBBBBBBBB
```

I also get the memory of the NSString object:

```
(lldb) fr v
(ViewController *const) self = 0x0897eb10
(SEL) _cmd = "viewDidLoad"
(NSString *) theKey = 0x00004664 @"BBBBBBBBBB"
```

When regarding the memory of the NSString object I only get strange values:

```
(lldb) memory read 0x00004664
0x00004664: 50 93 87 01 c8 07 00 00 68 37 00 00 0b 00 00 00  P.......h7......
0x00004674: 50 93 87 01 c8 07 00 00 74 37 00 00 0b 00 00 00  P.......t7......
```

This is, an NSString is not an array of char, and the memory contains … yes … what? How can I find the memory address where the characters stored in my NSString are stored?

Comment: NSStrings store characters in unicode, perhaps that's why the memory looks "strange"?
http://blog.ablepear.com/2010/06/objective-c-tuesdays-c-strings.html

Comment: `NSString` is definitely not just an array of char. It's a String class that is backed up with `CFString`. And as you can see [in CFString's source code](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-550.43/CFString.c), there's a lot of stuff.

Comment: So, NSString is an CFString. I found the following in the implementation file of CFString: `CF_EXPORT CFStringRef __CFStringMakeConstantString(const char *cStr);/* Private; do not use *` Looks good, doesn't it? But how can I access this pointer through the NSString instance?

Answer (score 5):

You asked:

> How can I find the memory address where the characters stored in my
>   NSString are stored?

In short, you can't. NSString is effectively opaque. The closest you're going to get is probably to call the `-UTF8String` method on it, which will give you a `const char*`, but if the string itself is not natively encoded with UTF8 encoding, then that pointer will not point to the "actual" data in the NSString, so...

Comment: Yeah, inspecting raw memory won't find data, it can only show pointers to data, or pointers to pointers to data...

Answer (score 3):

I recently had the same problem. You can use the following program to find 
the C pointer in memory of an `NSString`.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSString *a=@"@@@@@@@@@@@";
    const char *ptr = CFStringGetCStringPtr( (__bridge CFStringRef)a, 
                                             kCFStringEncodingMacRoman ) ;
    puts( ptr ) ; // find ptr
    NSLog(@"address:%p",ptr);
    NSLog(@"content:%s",ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

I found that the solution is to use `CFStringGetCStringPtr` to find the C pointer, which can then be used to find the `NSString` in memory.

Refer to: http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-1153.18/CFString.c

Comment: That's likely to do a conversion if required; there's no reason to believe it either will or won't disclose the current instance storage of an `NSString`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question. I wanted to see the bytes ( in hex ) that were stored in  memory for an NSString.

I started with this byte array:

```
const char bytes1[7] = { 0x05, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x00 }; // \0x512345
```

Placing a breakpoint, after `nsStrInput` was initialized - like @ipmcc said - the
 `UTF8String` method returned a Character array pointer.

```
(lldb) po [nsStrInput UTF8String]
0x0000000100769138

(lldb) mem read -c10 0x0000000100769138
0x100769138: 05 31 32 33 34 35 00 00 00 00                    .12345....
```

I could see my instance of NSString did hold the unprintable `ASCII` charactoer (`0x05`).  That was the answer I was hoping to find.